# How to use lapply to create new variables in a dataframe and rename them

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have some numeric variables in a dataframe. I want to create new variables that are mean-centered versions of the originals, add the new variables to my dataframe, and rename the new variables so they have the same names as the originals but with the suffix "_m".

At the moment, I can only do this in two steps, and I am subsetting using column indices, which isn't very flexible.

Is there a way to combine my two stage approach into one, and also avoid using column indexes so that the process works without having to count up how many columns I want to mean-center and then figuring out how many new columns this would mean adding to my dataframe? I don't have to use `lapply` if there's a better way.

Here is a simplified version of my current approach:

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:10], b = 1:10, c = 11:20)

df[4:5] <- lapply(df[2:3], function(x) {
      y <- scale(x, center = T, scale = F)
    }
)

names(df)[4:5] <- lapply(names(df)[2:3], function(x) {
    y <- paste0(x, "_m")
    }
)
```

Comment: `library(dplyr); fun1 <- function(x){scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)}; mutate_if(df, is.numeric, funs('_m' = fun1))`

Comment: @Sotos This is great, thanks, I didn't know about `mutate_if` or that you could change the names of columns using `funs`.

Comment: There is also `mutate_at` which can be handy for your case

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip @Sotos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base R, you could do

```
cbind(df, setNames(lapply(df[2:3], scale, scale=F),
                   paste0(names(df)[2:3], "_m")))
```

which returns

```
   a  b  c  b_m  c_m
1  a  1 11 -4.5 -4.5
2  b  2 12 -3.5 -3.5
3  c  3 13 -2.5 -2.5
4  d  4 14 -1.5 -1.5
5  e  5 15 -0.5 -0.5
6  f  6 16  0.5  0.5
7  g  7 17  1.5  1.5
8  h  8 18  2.5  2.5
9  i  9 19  3.5  3.5
10 j 10 20  4.5  4.5
```

The names of the new columns are applied with `setNames`.

Comment: @Imo Thanks, I didn't know about the `setNames` function. I was always using `names` but this solves my problem.